# Correct translation of "Sweet baking" and "Salty baking"

Tags: translation

I am website developer from the Czech Republic. I`ve got local website with recipes in czech language. I am going to make english version of my website but I am struggling with translation of two main categories: "Sweet baking" and "Salty baking".

In czech language it sound perfectly normal but I have feeling that it is not correct translation to english. To let you know what I mean, there are examples of recipes in each category:

- Sweet baking → all kinds of cakes, biscuits, apple strudel, gugelhupfs, sweet muffins
- Salty baking → quiches, meat pies, yorkshire pudding etc.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: you might want to use "sweet pastries" and "savory pastries" instead.

Comment: Savory  is the term, not salty. So you have ***sweet food and savory food*** -   Savoury food is salty or spicy and not sweet in taste. https://savoryandsweetfood.com/

Comment: Translating from French has a similar issue with *salé*.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410927/salty-or-savory